# How to put cards in an Integer array

Tags: arrays

I'm working on a project on how to make a game of "BlackJack" I made a .txt file with each of the cards names. My issue is I want to make each card worth a point value("9 of Clubs = 9, Queen of Hearts = 10, Ace of Clovers = 1 or 11, Etc.) And I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Which language are you using?

I would suggest you to use a Hash Table based array.

For example, if you are developing a project in PHP, you can use associative arrays to do that.

$array['QueenofHearts'] = 9;

Answer (score 0):

In a game of blackjack, you **don't have to care** if your card is either an 9 of Clubs or a 9 of Hearth. (If you want to be graphic, you can add a little something to show cards, but from a pure algorithm point of view, you don't need that information.)

Secondly, it's all about odds. Now if i remember correctly, there are 48 cards who got a value from 2 to 10 (The Queen, Jack & king got 10 value), and 4 cards who can be either a 1 or a 11.

Now that you know that, all you need is an Integer tab of 52 elements (your cards) that you'll fill with value going from 1 to 10.
At each draw, you'll randomize inside that array, and if you got a 1, you'll need to ask the value (Either 1 or 11), in any other case, you'll just need to add that value to the player's hand.

I think it's better if your first version of the game **doesnt care** about wich color the card is, but rather focus on the actual implementation of the gameplay.
Have fun !